# Changing <span> without effecting <span class="something">

Tags: html, css

I have a problem to change `<span>` in CSS without changing anything on `<span class="something">`

HTML

```
<span class="something">Some text</span>
<span>Another text</span>
```

CSS

```
span.something {
 color: #FFF;
}

span {
 display: block;
}
```

I'm expecting that all other `<span>` will have the style of `display:block` except for `<span class="something">`. Appreciate if anyone could help me on this. Thanks!

Comment: What you want the span something to be instead of display: block?

Comment: I just don't want it to change to display: block. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [`:not` selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp) which you can use as

```
span:not(.something) {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Give him a check for his answer

Answer (score 2):

The css negation pseudo-class is what you want.

```
span.something {
 color: #FFF;
}

span:not(.something) {
 display: block;
}
```